# Open tag issue when inserting model into forms in Django

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

I've a model in Django called "Bank". The bank model has an attribute called "currencies" which describes what type of currency they handle (e.g. USD, EUR etc). While creating a modelform to create a new bank, I wanted some specific formatting on my drop-down to select a currency and thus have the following code:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Currency</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <select id="currency_id" class="form-control" required>
            <option value={{form.currency}}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code works, however if I try to close the option tag by writing the following:

```
<option value={{form.currency}}></option>
```

The dropdown will show but with a ">" at the end of the dropdown. Why is this generated? I feel like there is some issue with my css when my HTML only works without me closing the tag.

Comment: have you tried `<option value="{{ form.currency }}"></option>`, note the quotes

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I tried, but instead of a '>' I get both the double quote and '>' after, like this: ">

Comment: @Tahu have you inspected the generated HTML (in the browser: right click and "inspect element") ? Maybe `form.currency` is already outputing HTML not just the model field values.